# When is User Signed In Current Principal

Tags: asp.net-core

Starting from the default `Asp.net 5 MVC` template which uses authorization I am trying to check for the `User` claims inside the `Login` controller action.

What I am not able to grasp is exactly when does `User.IsSignedIn()` becomes `true`.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
   if (User.IsSignedIn())
   /* more code */
}
```

In the code above `User.IsSignedIn()` returns `false`

But in the action right after this one, it retuns `true`

Where does the Signing in really occurs?

I would expect it to be done during `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` but, apparently, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET Identity authentication is based on cookies the `User.IsSignedIn()` method returns `true` if the authentication cookie is set for current request. This cookie is created by `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(..)` and stored in the response (not the request) of the action method.

The next action method will receive the cookie in the request and that's why you'll see `User.IsSignedIn()` return `true` in that method and not in the method that actually performs the sign in.